# VSTO version 40820 download link

Tags: vsto, installshield

Where I can download VSTO Office Runtime *version 10.0.40820*?
I need link for this specific version, NOT for the newest one (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158918).

Why I need this specific version? I created custom InstallShield .PRQ for VSTO that download file from web and checks if file is not corrupted using MD5 hash.
If I use generic download link and MS will deploy new version of VSTO then setup will complaint about corrupted file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstallShield has abstractions in their PRQ file that are meant to help but I have found problematic.

First, the PRQ itself can have a URL.  This means that at runtime the PRQ embedded into the setup.exe will go try to download a newer version of itself from this URL.  If this happens, the new XML is used and yours is ignored.    This sounds like a good idea to keep things fresh and up to date but the CM Nazi in me see's this as a man in the middle vunerability that compromises the integrity of the build.

The second is that your XML or the downloaded XML both have URL attributes on the individual files.  Again the CM Nazi in me says that while this seems like a good idea, it's really inserting an external dependency that isn't under my control and again violating the integrity of the build.

If it was me, I'd never use InstallShield and/or Microsoft URL's in my PRQ files.  Host the content yourself and do change management of that so you can have complete control.   If longevity of the build is desired then don't use web downloads in the first place.  Bake it all into the EXE.

As for the exact question you asked, I'll have to google for it.  But really I'd probably just move onto the latest version and then implement the above advice starting there.

Comment: The link you posted IS for 10.0.40820.0 which is what you ask for.  Please tell me MSFT didn't publish the same version twice. :)  An older version I can find is 10.0.31007.0 and it's found on my hard drive in the PFX86\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages directory (installed by Visual Studio 2010 )

Comment: I don't understand.  You ask for that version and then you say the link is for that version.  Something is being lost in communication.

Comment: Now (15 November) this link points to version 10.0.40820, but in the future when Microsoft release new version of VSTO Runtime e.g. 11.0 this link will point to that new version. This link is used by e.g. ClickOnce to get _newest_ available version of VSTOR, but I needed exactly version 10.0.40820.